# How to hide or display data when i click on contact button for below image

Tags: php, html, mongodb

[In this image i fetched the data from mongodb and i would like to add buttons for contacts for each record and i want it it works like toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/198jG.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here Is Example :

```js
$('button').click(function(){
 $('div').slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Show &amp; Hide
</div>
<button>
Contact
</button>
```

Comment: how can i apply it for the multiple rows